# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

I've got a problem with my ReactJS App with getting data from api. I still have an error: 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined', and I have no idea why it's happening.

My code:
**UsersList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { Card, Container, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import User from './User'

class ProfilesList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      fetched: false,
      loading: false,
    };
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
      loading : true
    });
    fetch('http://58be98154389c312007f403f.mockapi.io/users/users').then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>{
      this.setState({
        users : res.results,
        loading : true,
        fetched : true
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const {fetched, loading, users} = this.state;
    let content;
    if(fetched){
      content = <div>{this.state.users.map((user,index) =>
      <User key={user.username} id={index+1} user={user}/>)}</div>;
    }
    else if(loading && !fetched){
        content = <p> Loading ...</p>;
    }
    else{
      content = (<div></div>);
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProfilesList;
```

**User.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Card, Container, Icon } from 'semantic-ui-react'


class User extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {user, id} = this.props;
    return (
      <Card
        image='http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar/large/elliot.jpg'
        header={user.username}
        meta='Friend'
        description='Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'
        extra={(
          <a>
            <Icon name='user' />
            16 Friends
          </a>
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this.state.users is obviously undefined. Check your API response after the fetch function returns, what is in res.results?

Comment: I think it doesn't return anything

Comment: Well check it out, and if it is the case, then don't update your state.

Comment: I'll check it, thanks

Comment: Also, when you get the result, you want to set loading: false

Comment: It's look like I didn't got any response from API

Comment: Well then, go fix that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `state.users` is undefined when you try to do `this.state.users.map()` in your `render` function. So task #1 is to figure out why your `fetch()` is returning undefined and fix that. It's a good idea to build in some handling for cases when you get undefined results or other errors and set your state appropriately. Additionally, I tend to check that an expected array is not `undefined` before I try to `map` it, like this:

```
{
    expectedArray
    ?
        expectedArray.map(someMappingFunction)
    :
        <div>expectedArray was 'undefined' or otherwise 'falsy'</div>
}
```

Such a conditional statement is called a "ternary" and is very useful because it can be embedded in JSX as an "if/else" statement. It has the form `(condition) ? (expression if true) : (expression if false)`. For example:

```
var foo = 7;
var bar = (foo % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd";
console.log(bar); // "Odd"
```